# Complex linq to entity query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an EF model with 3 tables , `Artist`, `Movie` and `Movie_Artist_Job`.
`Movie_Artist_Job` is just a foreign key table :

```
MovieId,ArtistId,JobId.
```

I m trying to get a results like this :

> ArtistName1, Movie1
>
> ArtistName1, Movie2
>
> Artistname2, Movie1
>
> Artistname2, Movie3
>
> etc...

Right now I am doing this :

```
var query = (
    from items in _objEntities.Movie_Artist_Job
    where items.Artist.FulleName != string.Empty
    select items.Artist.FulleName).Distinct<string>();

List<ThumbItem> Items = new List<ThumbItem>();

foreach (string fullName in query)
{
    var matching = (
        from movie in _objEntities.Movie_Artist_Job
        where movie.Artist.FulleName == fullName
        select movie.Movie)
        .Distinct<Movie>();

    if (matching.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (Movie movies in matching)
        {
            if (movies != null && movies.IsDeleted == false)
            {
                new ThumbItem(fullName, movies.title);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but it takes ages...

Any clue on how to optimism this ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried profiling this? You can use the SQL profiler to find out which queries are executed under the covers. My bet is that 1. too many queries are executed and 2. you are missing some database indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've tried to replicate the DB you mentioned: -

1. Artists
2. Movies
3. Jobs

and i add one entity class thumbItem as the following; to select items to: -

```
internal class ThumbItem
{
    public string ArtistName { set; get; }
    public string MovieName { set; get; }
}
```

and i have performed the following function to get the result you requested: -

```
MoviesEntities context = new MoviesEntities();

        var Thumbs = from artist in context.Artists
                     join job in context.Jobs on artist.ID equals job.ArtistID
                     join movie in context.Movies on job.MovieID equals movie.ID
                     select new ThumbItem()
                                {
                                    ArtistName = artist.Name,
                                    MovieName = movie.Name
                                };


        dataGridView1.DataSource = Thumbs;
```

it worked very fast and didn't take anything, i think your problem was that you separated the matching and the creation of controls into different steps other than performing a join statement with select into entity; which was the time consuming action.

EDIT: -

New Question from comment: - need the number of movies per artist from the same query?

just add this code after the one before it'll get you the result with DB round trip: -

```
var ListByArtist = Thumbs.ToList().GroupBy(l => l.ArtistName).Select(lg => new
                        {
                            Artist = lg.Key,
                            NumberOfMovies = lg.Count()
                        });
```

Comment: hello OmarQa, Your Code rocks :) thanks a lot for you quick help. Any chance to get the numbers of movies for each artist using your query ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the complement, you can get the number of movies for each artist by selecting a grouped by count from the thumb item list, I've edited my answer you can check it, hope this is what you need and good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You query the database inside a loop. This results in N + 1 queries. Try rewriting your code to the following:

```
var query = (
    from items in _objEntities.Movie_Artist_Job
    where items.Artist.FulleName != string.Empty
    select items.Artist.FulleName)
    .Distinct();

var matching =
    from fullName in query
    from movie in _objEntities.Movie_Artist_Job
    where movie.Artist.FulleName == fullName
    where !movies.IsDeleted
    select new { movie.fullName, movie.title })
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();

List<ThumbItem> Items = (
    from movie in matching
    select new ThumbItem(movie.fullName, movie.title))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but the answer from OmarQa is very fast. BTW thanks a lot for taking time helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You are handling many many relationship in a bit awkward manner. The easier approach will be to have this table as following with an primary key

```
public class Movie_Artist_Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

Then, simply call `db.Movie_Artist_Job.ToList()`

Comment: Agree with your approach but i m not using code first, so i have to manage the existing Db schema.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called "pivoting", you should take a look at [Linq Extensions Library](http://linqlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pivot&referringTitle=Home) on how to achieve this on a properly build EF model.

As a side note, the all point of EF is to be able to write your queries in natural object oriented way, that is you shouldn't care much about "Movie_Artist_Job" table on the C# side of things (Calling Artist.Movies should return the list of movies for a given artist)